# How can i Get Columns from the Views type collections in MongoDB using c#

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver, spring-data-mongodb

How can i Get Columns from the Views type collections in MongoDB using c#

I am using this code for getting columns from mongoDB collections. Normal collections it will work but Views type collections is not working.
So i need column names from views type of collections.

```
var client = new MongoClient(Connstr);
var DB = client.GetDatabase(dbname);           
var collection = DB.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(tablename);
var cursor = collection.FindAsync(new 
    BsonDocument()).Result.ToListAsync().Result;        
foreach (BsonDocument document in cursor)
{
    Type type;
    var typestring = Enum.GetName(typeof(BsonType), 
    column.Value.BsonType);
    Columnlist.Add(column.Name);
}
```

[image]

In above image "AnalyticsView" is a view type collection.

I am using MongoDb Driver for Getting columns.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: @Mahdi "view type is not supporting for find method " This is the error. Sop i need a solution for getting records from view type collection.. :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation:

> Views are read-only; write operations on views will [throw] error.
> The following read operations can support views:
>
> - db.collection.find()
> - db.collection.findOne()
> - db.collection.aggregate()
> - db.collection.count()
> - db.collection.distinct()

So, I created a view which concatenates the first name and last name of the employees in the `employee` collection. You can find the view example [here](https://dzone.com/articles/taking-a-look-at-mongodb-views). Then I added a class in my code for the view as follows (my view will have one property which is `Fullname`):

```
public class EmployeeName
{
    [BsonElement("fullname")]
    public string Fullname { get; set; }
}
```

The rest is done like this:

```
var context = new Context();
var builder = Builders<EmployeeName>.Filter;
var filter = builder.Eq(x => x.Fullname, "John Smith");
var test = context.EmployeeView.Find(filter).SingleOrDefault();
```